# Learning about Windows Deployment

Tags: windows, deployment, adk

I'm searching for a course, how to learn the most out of Windows Deployment. I've asked a couple of questions here about specific actions in this technology, but this isn't really effective if I had to keep asking questions about the same thing over and over again.

The desired result what I want to get out of this would be:

- Creating a fully customized and unattended Windows installation .ISO file, to "my" personal needs (programs, settings, etc).
- Creating a fully customized and unattended Windows installation .ISO file, to cover enterprise situations such as different PC models or different needs of specific software.

The thing I'd like to avoid is having a different interface then just the normal Windows setup. For example, LiteTouch with MDT.

Can someone give me an course or book recommendation for learning Windows deployment for these kind of needs?

Comment: This question is off topic [What topics can I ask about here ?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like Where would this be a good place to ask?

Comment: see if this gets you started https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-243.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a google search for ["Windows 7 deployment learning resources"](https://www.google.dk/search?q=windows%207%20deployment%20learning%20portal) led me to this:

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/deploying-windows-7

I'm sure you can find other resources if you have a look around.

Comment: Thank you, but as i've said, most things that i found are about specific subjects.

Comment: I can not personally recommend any learning material, as I have not studied this subject formally, so I would be basing my recommedations of other peoples opinions.